# Eclipse and m2e: how to automatically exclude a resource folder from JAR?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a Maven 3 project. I store the project config files into the src/main/config directory. I use Eclipse with m2e plugin. I want the config files to be on the classpath, so I declare the src/main/config directory as a resource directory in the parent POM. But, I don't want the config files to be in my JAR.
When I declare src/main/config as a resource directory, and that I update the project configuration with m2eclipse, it automatically adds src/main/config as a source folder but with excluded="**". The Maven builder plugin adds the resources to the classpath.

But, I want my config files to be on the classpath but not in my JAR.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of config files are these files cause it sounds a little bit confusing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it may be configured in the maven-jar-plugin. The maven-resources-plugin copies the content of src/main/config to the target/classes directory because src/main/config is declared as resource in the POM. And, to exclude the files from the JAR, I used  element in the maven-jar-plugin  element to exclude my config files.

Answer (score 1):

I could achieve the same with following configuration in pom.xml :-

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) to specify the config files you don't wish to include in your jar.

Comment: The maven-resources-plugin does not what I want. If I exclude the config files with this plugin, they are not copied to target/classes, so I can't run my project from the IDE. The solution is to configure the maven-jar-plugin and to let the maven-resources-plugin copy the files to the output directory.